# Css specification: what has more "weight"

Tags: css

In css specification what will affect more an **inline** style or external !important

```
<div id="di" style="color: red;"></div>
```

External "style.css":

```
#di{color: green!important;}
```

The div text color will be red or green?

Does it mather here, if i use class or id?

I got this situation that got me thinking about the previous on:

```
<div id="di"><img src=".." /></div>
```

-> i am trying to change the image from CSS, is it possible?
when i tried to use

```
background-image: url(...)!important;
```

from an external stylesheet it didn't effect the "div". there is solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**!important** declaration gives priority over rule specificity but is better to be avoided as it cannot get overridden without another **!important** rule usage.

> CSS attempts to create a balance of power between author and user
>   style sheets. By default, rules in an author's style sheet override
>   those in a user's style sheet (see cascade rule 3).
>
> However, for balance, an "!important" declaration (the delimiter token
>   "!" and keyword "important" follow the declaration) takes precedence
>   over a normal declaration. Both author and user style sheets may
>   contain "!important" declarations, and user "!important" rules
>   override author "!important" rules. This CSS feature improves
>   accessibility of documents by giving users with special requirements
>   (large fonts, color combinations, etc.) control over presentation.

```css
#di{color: green!important;}
```

```html
<div id="di" style="color: red;">test</div>
```

Reference: [!important rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)

Comment: Thanks, if i have this situation <div id="di"><img src=".." /></div
-> i am trying to change the image from CSS, is it possible?
when i tried to use "background-image: url(...)!important" from an external stylesheet it didn't effect the "div". there is solution for that?

Comment: Unfortunately no, you need javascript help for that.

Comment: Thanks emmanuel! You can add the second answer to the primary anwser- I updated the question.

Comment: If you are familiar with jquery [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) should help you.

Comment: Yes i am familiar, I will tell you why i wanted to use CSS- it's a WORDPRESS site and i don't want to change the template itself (update will override)

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a css option.